# XmlValidationError - How to get the wrong xml-row

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I have a really long xml (aprox. 17000 rows) and get a xmlvalidationerror when i validate thia against an xsd. Has anyone an idea/tool/best practice how to find the wrong part in the xml? My code is in .net.

[Solution]
I used the following webapp http://www.corefiling.com/opensource/schemaValidate.html

Comment: What's exactly the error message? On .NET you should see line number and position when loading the Xml document from a stream (as opposed to a node reader in which case you would see 0, 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say 17000 rows, that definitely slows down the editor. Despite of that one can give a try going through XML. It's uncertain having error message containing no line number and column number (even if it throws one error at once) .. I mean usually validation error message contain line number and column number.

in such case, I open up the XML file in either Microsoft visual studio or notepad++, choose pretty-print option (incase if XML isn't properly aligned)..

based on validator that you use, error messages may contain XPath as-well, in such cases I use XPath evaluation in notepad++

Notepad++ has XML tools plug-in, its free and very useful. And can handle files as heavy as few MBs.

Comment: http://space.dl.sourceforge.net/project/npp-plugins/XML%20Tools/Xml%20Tools%202.3.2%20r908%20Unicode%20Beta4/xmltools_2.3.2_r908_unicode_beta4.zip

Comment: You need to download above plug-in (copy all dlls to `"\Program Files\Notepad++\"` folder!) .. you will be able to see XML Tools under Plug-in menu.

Comment: open XML, click on Pretty-print xml, under Plug-ins-->XML Tools

Comment: also click on XML under Language menu, that will colorize the file :)